# sweetalert pop up if passwords don't match

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

I want to make good pop up to my project with sweetalert when the passwords don't match:

```
const SignUp = ({ signUpStart, userError, resetError }) => {
  const [userCredentials, setUserCredentials] = useState({
    displayName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = userCredentials;

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert(`password don't match`);
      return;
    }

    signUpStart({ displayName, email, password });
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setUserCredentials({ ...userCredentials, [name]: value });
  };

  return (
    <div className="signup">
      <h2 className="title">I do not have a account</h2>
      <span>Sign up with your email </span>
      <form className="sign-up-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form
          type="text"
          name="displayName"
          value={displayName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Display Name"
          required
        ></Form>
        <Form
          type="email"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Email"
          required
        ></Form>
        <Form
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Password"
          required
        ></Form>
        <Form
          type="password"
          name="confirmPassword"
          value={confirmPassword}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Confirm Password"
          required
        ></Form>
        <CustomButton type="submit">SIGN UP</CustomButton>
      </form>
      {userError && userError.message ? (
        <SweetAlert
          show={!!userError.message}
          type="warning"
          title="Something went wrong"
          text={userError.message}
          onConfirm={() => resetError()}
        />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

EDIT: i add my whole component to the question. i deleted my mapstatetoprops and dispatch.

So i basically want to run once when i hit my submit button.
I want to make the alert in the `if` statement. But I think I need to refactor little. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: No, my question is how to do it in the if statement. I know how to use it, because i use it in another way in my project. But i don't know how to do the alert only when i press the sign up button.

Comment: please share some code like sign up button so we can get your que exactly.

Comment: To show this alert, you need to Set Message in `userError.message` which is in `props`. One way to do that would be to provide `setError` prop like: `({ signUpStart, userError, resetError, setError })` and when called it should set error in `message` property of `userError` object. And right after that - on click of "OK" in the alert, you can calll **resetError**.

Comment: little confusing, because im new to react, but i try to understand it.

Comment: im importing from sweetalert2-react

Comment: import SweetAlert from "sweetalert2-react";
yes here is my import

Comment: Currently, you have put 2 conditions (`{userError && userError.message ?` and `show={!!userError.message}`) to show the alert, 1 (this `show={!!userError.message}`) is enough. I think you are keeping your `userError` object in Redux. So, you need to set `userError` in redux store. As soon as `userError` will have data in `message` property, the alert will be shown. Go through [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sweetalert2-react) to know more about this alert.

Comment: yeag my user error in redux selector

Comment: If it is difficult for you, you may want to switch to, simpler library, https://sweetalert.js.org/guides and use it without Redux (manage your error message and flag in local state).

Comment: Yes, i think this is better solution,because i only want to make simple alert